# something wrong with regex

Tags: java, regex, email

That's my first project when I use regex and I have a little problem when I'm validating email. I use the following formula: `^[0-9]{5,6}+(@student\\\.de)|(@teacher\\\.de)` (it starts with 5 or 6 numbers and then are two alternative domains). But it's still doesn't work and I can't find the mistake in the formula. Could anyone help me?

Comment: Please give us some inputs.

Comment: for example: 23970@student.de
45342@student.de
34224@teacher.de

Comment: You're missing the right grouping with that alternation `^[0-9]{5,6}@(student|teacher)\.de` and `{5,6}+` is a nested quantifier error. Java doesn't support it.

Comment: Where you say doesn't work what does that mean? No match? exception? Please share code too

Comment: yes, I've searched, but I still don't know :/ probably it's very easy to solve, but I can't

Comment: the addition sign ... what for ? you chould choose between numeric quantifier or asterisk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
^[0-9]{5,6}@(student|teacher)\.de$
```

This assumes that you want a five or six digit number (possibly with proceeding zeros) followed by an at sign followed by either the student or the teacher domain.

Comment: I've used it and it works cool. but I' ve got another question: I must use more complex domain: student.university.city.de or student.university.edu.de and for teachers: teacher.university.city.de or teacher.university.edu.de. I use: '((student\\.university\\.city)|(student\\.university\\.edu)‌​|(teacher\\.universi‌​ty\\.city)|teacher\\‌​.university\\.edu)\\‌​.de$' Could you help me with it? And thanks for your time :)

Comment: Looks like you are escaping the backslashes and you did not enclose the last domain in its own set of parentheses. Try `^[0-9]{5,6}@((student\.university\.city)|(student\.university\.edu)‌​‌​|(teacher\.univer‌​si‌​ty\.city)|(teach‌​er\.university\.‌​edu))\​.de$`

Comment: now it work well. thanks man

Comment: Read this and decide whether to mark my answer: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14994/do-you-feel-dirty-if-you-nudge-new-users-to-accept-your-answer-when-they-indicat

Answer (score 0):

I whould like to use `^[0-9]{5,6}@(teacher|student)\.de` instead, which mean start with 5 or 6 degits followed by `@teacher.de` or `@student.de`

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/w3X54G/1)